# How to force user to input value in javascript prompt?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code, which will open a prompt box. But the problem is whether user inputs value in or not, it still proceeds the code if user click Ok. Is there anyway to force user to input value in, then click OK else they can not click Ok button.

Here is what i tried but i did not work.

```
$(function() {
$(".adminapprovepost").click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var tag = prompt("you must enter one keyword to approve this post");
if(tag!=null)
{
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/admin/admin-approve-post.php",
  data: {id:id,tag:tag},
   success: function(){
   }
  });
 $(this).parents(".postrecord").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
.animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
}
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: `var tag = null; while(!tag) { tag = prompt("...").trim(); }`

Comment: Use jQuery UI modal dialog instead of this which can only be stopped in Chrome if the user wants to not stay

Comment: `tag = prompt("…").trim();` does not work when the user clicks cancel because then `null` is being returned. And `null` can't be trimmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".adminapprovepost").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var proceed = true;
        while(proceed) {
            tag = prompt("you must enter one keyword to approve this post");
            if (typeof(tag) == "string") {
                tag = tag.trim()
                if (tag!="")) {
                    proceed = false;
                }
            }
            if (tag===null) {
                proceed = false;
            }
        }
        if(tag!=null)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/admin/admin-approve-post.php",
                data: {id:id,tag:tag},
                success: function(){
                }
            });
            $(this).parents(".postrecord").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
            .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Edit: Now the user can also click 'cancel'. And it finally should work. (I hope…)

Comment: the problem is that i can not click Cancel button to quit the script?

Comment: if i click cancel, i got this error: TypeError: prompt(...) is null. How to prevent this please?

Comment: Changed it but still got this error: TypeError: prompt(...) is null... When i click cancel

Comment: I edited my code to your latest code but still when i click cancel, i catched this error: TypeError: prompt(...) is null...

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for your patience. I made too many simple mistakes in a row. I should stop working for today...

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
    var proceed = false;
    while(!proceed) 
    {
        tag = prompt("Please input the string:");
        if (typeof(tag) == "string") 
        {
            tag = tag.trim();


            if (tag=="")//// no value
            {
                proceed = false;
                alert('Invalid entry!!!');
            }
            else
            {
              proceed=true;

            }
        }
        if (tag===null) ////cancel hits
        {
            proceed = false;
            alert('Approve process cancelled !!!');
            break;
        }
    }
    if(proceed)
    {
      /////put your code here
    }
```

The while loop will go on asking you for the string unless you hit the cancel button in the prompt or put a valid entry.

Comment: the while loop will go on asking you for the string unless you hit the cancel button in the prompt or put a valid entry

Answer (score 0):

Your test is wrong because the prompt my return space-like characters or an empty string (which actually happens when the user just clicks on OK). I would write:

```
var tag = prompt("you must enter one keyword to approve this post");
if (tag != null) tag = tag.trim(); // assuming here you really want to do this
if (!tag) { // a non-empty value
  :
```